# Why does my C++ program's memory usage keep growing?

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I am new to Linux and C++ and have a question about the memory usage of my application.

My application processes a lot of real-time data, about **500** messages per second.

I use std::map to manage (i.e., insert and erase) all the messages. For example,

```
std::map<int, data_struct> m_map;

// when receive a new message, convert the message into a data structure
m_map.insert(std::pair<int, data_struct>(message.id, data));

// when need to erase a message
iter = m_map.find(id);
if (iter != m_map.end()) {
    m.map.erase(iter);
}
```

The size of the m_map is roughly about **2500**, i.e., the application receives a lot new message at the beginning, then gradually need to erase messages. After about 10 seconds, it reaches a point that the number of new message received is about the same as the messages need to be erased.

My question is this, after about 20 minutes, in the Linux **System Monitor**, I noticed the memory my application uses is about 1GB. And it seems the size doubles every 20 minutes. Is this something normal, does the application really use that much memory? Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably have a memory leak. Either that or your application isn't keeping up as well as you think it is. Most people would probably use a message queue for something like this (like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) for example).

Comment: Maybe there's some specific reason why you're doing it, but you could just use `map.erase(id)`.  There's a version of erase that takes the key as a parameter and returns the number of elements deleted.

Comment: What does data_struct look like?

Comment: Copy one of the many "make_unique" functions to your code, and use smart pointers.  Odds are, that will solve your problem, and many others you never knew you had.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your program allocates and deallocates chunks of memory often, you get [fragemtation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computer%29) - there is only so much the OS can do to make sure there are no gaps between the chunks of memory you have allocated.  But generally, the memory usage resulting from this will plateau.

If your program's memory is *continually* increasing, you have a memory leak - either you are forgetting to `delete` objects (or call `free()` in the case of C-style allocations) or you are accumulating your objects in a container and forgetting to remove them.

For finding missing `delete` calls, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)!

using valgrind to detect memory leaks is as simple as installing it using your favorite package manager and then running

```
valgrind my_program
```

Your program will run and when it's finished, valgrind will dump a terribly detailed report of memory leaks and where they came from, including complete stack traces.

valgrind is awesome.

Comment: @michael, thanks for the advice. Could you please provide a link or an example of how to use valgrind to find missing delete calls, memory leakage, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

map::erase() calls your object's destructor method, so you should there for memory leaks

maybe, if you can measure how much the used memory increased, and the size of your data structures, you get a good hint about where the problem is.

you get about 600.000 messages every 20 min. If memory usage doubles from 1GB to 2GB, you get something like 1.8kB loss per message (1GB / 600.000 messages in 20min)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Memory usage increasing means more than just leaking.

Is RSS (Resident Size) increasing ?
Or
Is VSZ (Virtual Size) increasing?

You can find out by running "ps -aux"

What I have experienced is if RSS stays same and VSZ keeps increasing then its sure is memory leak.

If RSS keeps growing and your VSZ stabilises at some point, then you are touching lot of memory everytime and also you are increasing the amount of memory you are touching, finding this out in your code is tough.